# aspell (mac homebrew) runs, but cannot spellcheck because of missing(?) cset file

Tags: homebrew, aspell

I am having trouble with my aspell upon installing it on my new macbook.

Aspell exists, and works in the sense of the executable works:

```
❯ aspell -v
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.8.1)
```

However, if I use it to check spelling, it complains:

```
❯ cat ~/text.txt | aspell -a
.cset" could not be opened for reading or does not exist.homebrew/Cellar/aspell/0.60.8.1_1/lib/aspell-0.60/
```

At first I thought it was a flyspell/emacs error, which complains about `"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aspell/0.60.8.1_1/lib/aspell-0.60/ .cset" could not be opened`, so there could be a mac-related lineending error? Aspell worked out of the box on my old machine, not sure if that would help.

Am I correct in reading that it's trying to find an "empty" cset, which of course wouldn't work? What should I be looking at here, any help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

With macOS 14.4, I have:

```
$ aspell -v
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.8.1)
```

Running:

```
$ echo My apple is good. > text.txt
$ cat text.txt | aspell -a
```

Gives me:

```
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.8.1)
*
*
*
*
```

Which seems OK.

So I suggest a reinstallation of aspell:

```
brew reinstall aspell
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried that already, with no difference. :/

Comment: @ChristophSafferling What happens if you run `brew uninstall aspell` and then `ls /opt/homebrew/Cellar/aspell`? Is there still some files? What about the output of `brew doctor`?

Comment: Brew doctor says your system is ready to brew, and when I brew uninstall aspell, `/opt/homebrew/Cellar` no longer has an `aspell` dir. That's why I'm a bit at a miss. I think it's some kind of dos fileending issue, but I do not know where.